# What does actually return `ioctl` `SIOCGIFCONF` on Android?

Tags: android, c++, sockets, android-ndk

In Linux, it is possible to get network interfaces names and addresses list with `ioctl`, for example, with following code:

```
using boost::format;
using namespace std;
string report;
struct ifconf network_adapters;
network_adapters.ifc_len = 0;
network_adapters.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf = nullptr;
int udp_connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
int ioctl_result = ioctl(udp_connection, SIOCGIFCONF, &network_adapters);
vector<char> buf(static_cast<size_t>(network_adapters.ifc_len));
network_adapters.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf = buf.data();
ioctl_result = ioctl(udp_connection, SIOCGIFCONF, &network_adapters);
for(int offset = 0; offset < network_adapters.ifc_len; offset += sizeof(struct ifreq))
{
    struct ifreq *network_adapter = reinterpret_cast<struct ifreq *>(network_adapters.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf + static_cast<size_t>(offset));
    char ip_address[4096];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &network_adapter->ifr_ifru.ifru_addr, ip_address, 4096);
    report.append((format("%1% = %2%\r\n") % network_adapter->ifr_ifrn.ifrn_name % ip_address).str());
}
```

I expect to get `name = ip` lines for IP4 interfaces with this code, example:

```
lo = 127.0.0.1
wlan0 = 192.168.1.132
```

For any reason, however, address value is `2.0.0.0` always in Android OS.

According to `netdevice(7)`, the `ifreq` structure is union that may contain a lot of different information. How to understand (where is it documented) what specific information `ifreq` contains on Android?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ifr_addr to access ip address of the interface

```
    struct ifreq *network_adapter = reinterpret_cast<struct ifreq *>(network_adapters.ifc_ifcu.ifcu_buf + static_cast<size_t>(offset));
    struct sockaddr_in* ipaddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&network_adapter->ifr_addr;
    char *ip_address = inet_ntoa(ipaddr->sin_addr);
```